# Adding simple whatsapp share Button to Wordpress

Tags: android, html, button, share, whatsapp

I tried all the Information I could find. But im too stupid to make it work. Im not a programmer. Would love to offer my readers on my blog a share button to whatsapp.

the following was working half way.

`<a href="whatsapp://send?text=The text to share!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>`

its opening whatsapp but its not fetching the current page url link.
how could I make this work?
to share easy and fast current page urls via whatsapp as a link. in best case in android and ios.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
<a href="" target="_blank" onclick="this.href='https://wa.me/?text=Have a look at:'+location.href">WA</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much works wonderfully. have a great day man.

Comment: unfortunately after saving the wordpress text. the inline javascript dissappears always and the onclick function is not workin anymore. maybe wordpress cant deal with it within a text. do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=https://linktopreview.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Share on Whatsapp</a>
```

You need to include the url